# Why isn't Promise.catch handler called for any exception in Promise.then handler?

Tags: javascript, async-await

In the following Javascript code, why is the exception caught in example 1 and 2, but not in example 3?

```js
const f1 = async () => {
  console.log("f1()");
}
const f2 = async () => {
  throw new Error("error from f2");
}
const errorHandler = (error) => {
  console.error("caught in errorHandler: " + error);
}

// Example 1 (caught):
f1().then(() => { throw new Error("error from anonymous") }).catch(errorHandler);

// Example 2 (caught):
f1().then(async () => { await f2(); }).catch(errorHandler);

// Example 3 (not caught):
f1().then(() => { f2(); }).catch(errorHandler);
```

In particular, examples 1 and 3 appear to be completely identical to me, but why is one caught and not the other?

Comment: 1 and 3 are not the same.  The `async` marker on `f2` makes them different. If 1 looked this they would be roughly the same. `() => { new Promise(() => throw new Error("error from anonymous") } }`

Answer (score 1):

Because in Example 3 the result of the `f2()` function is ignored.  It is neither awaited not returned as part of the Promise chain.

Either await it:

```
f1().then(async () => { await f2(); }).catch(errorHandler);
```

Which will implicitly return a `Promise`.

Or explicitly return its `Promise`:

```
f1().then(() => f2()).catch(errorHandler);
```

or simply:

```
f1().then(f2).catch(errorHandler);
```

---

> In particular, examples 1 and 3 appear to be completely identical to me

The key difference here is that Example 1 isn't doing anything asynchronous in the `.then()` callback, whereas Example 3 is.  Both throw an exception, but Example 3 throws that exception from within an asynchronous operation.  And since that operation isn't being awaited, there's nothing to handle that exception.

Comment: Thanks David, between your answer and Armen's it's making sense.  However, when I marked example 1 as async, the error was still caught: f1().then(async () => { throw new Error("error from anonymous") }).catch(errorHandler);

Comment: @Paul: But the operation still isn't internally doing anything asynchronous.  Making the `.then()` callback *itself* `async` is fine because the underlying system knows to `await` it.  But when you call an `async` function from *within* that callback, your code needs to either `await` it or return the resulting `Promise` to be awaited by the system.

Answer (score 1):

Evaluating the expression `f2()`, `f2` being an `async` procedure, *always* returns a `Promise` and promises are *always* settled (fulfilled or rejected) *after* current script finishes executing. With or without `await`, `f2()` just creates a task on the task queue, but with `await` you're actually waiting for the promise it returns, to settle. Without `await`, you aren't.

Consider the effect of adding a call to `console.debug` after `f2()`:

```
f1().then(() => { f2(); console.debug("Hello."); }).catch(errorHandler);
```

With the above, "Hello." will be printed on the console immediately after the preceding call to `f2` returns with a promise, regardless whether the promise fulfills or rejects. The promise that `catch` is called on, fulfills with `undefined` -- because `() => { f2(); console.debug("Hello."); }` returns `undefined` / doesn't return anything nor does it throw -- `f2()` doesn't throw even if the promise it returns, was rejected.

Moving on, like I said, procedures marked `async` *always* return a promise, even for degenerate cases like e.g. the following:

```
const f3 = async () => 1; /// Returns a `Promise`, not `1`
console.assert(f3() instanceof Promise); /// Assertion valid because evaluating `f3()` yields a promise
console.assert((await f3()) instanceof Number); /// Assertion valid because evaluating `await f3()` yields `1`
```

Try `console.debug(f3())` -- `Promise` value will be printed. That's probably the piece of the puzzle you're missing -- it is the use of `await` that causes well, *waiting* on the promise and, if the promise is rejected, throwing the value it rejected with.

Now, if you look at your registering of `errorHandler` with the `catch` method in the third example, you're trying "catching" the error on the "wrong" promise. The promise returned by `then` method being called on the promise returned by `f1()`, is not the same promise as one returned by `f2()`, nor are the two related in any way. These are different promises and again, because of the first factor, the promise returned by `then` in your third example, doesn't reject -- it simply creates another promise with the `f2()` expression there, which rejects "later" while the former is fulfilled with `undefined` (because `() => { f2(); }` does not return anything), not causing any procedures registered with the `catch` method, to be called.

By the way, rejection of promises that aren't duly waited on -- no `await` -- can be "listened on" with registering an event handler on the global object (`window` in a Web browser, normally), for events of type `unhandledrejection`. But that's rightfully a last-resort "handling" which typically is done for logging/telemetry purposes, in quotes because you aren't handling the promise then, really -- it already rejected and whatever created it already had its chance to handle it but didn't which is why you end up with the "unhandled rejection" in the first place.

Comment: Your first paragraph was the critical bit that I wasn't understanding, and the rest was valuable re-enforcement.  Thank you!

Comment: That was my intent -- that the answer, while not necessarily hitting _the_ mark and being all you needed to understand what your problem was at the core, that it still could install the right kind of information needed to root out similar problems on your end in the future. One last tip I can give you is to not be afraid to read the [relevant `Promise`-related documentation by the standards body that defined it, ECMA](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/control-abstraction-objects.html#sec-promise-objects) -- it can border on heavy but IMO _is_ understandable with a strong cup of coffee ;)